# Getting the rotation of an object using NyARToolkit

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

I'm trying to use NyARToolkit for android to get the rotation of a marker.

I am trying to automatically straighten a document that has been photographed using the camera.

Does anyone know how I would go about this, using NyARtoolkit or another if necessary?